# How did T get into the agency?

Tags: men-in-black, men-in-black-2

In the first *Men in Black* movie, the Men in Black have a screening process to weed out potential problem agents, but in the first sequel J's partner T is clearly an idiot who doesn't know better than to provoke dangerous aliens (like 'Jeff', a large alien who lives under New York city)- how did someone like him get accepted as an MIB?

Comment: Stop using the standards of J & K. They are the best agents MiB has.

Comment: Presumably, not all MiB agents are field agents. T might have been space TSA agent before they tried him in a field agent role.

Answer (score 13):

Presumably T was the best of the best of the best (with honours!) at the time that the MiB needed additional staff, given that J has neuralysed a bunch of previous candidates.

Imagine [this recruitment scenario](https://youtu.be/THe_hlNE3yI?t=109), except without K whispering in Zed's ear. They would have likely recruited Jake Jensen or one the other "*ambitious recruits*" that have been selected by their trawl of other agencies, noting that Jake here almost certainly has a [4.0 GPA](https://www.collegesimply.com/colleges/new-york/united-states-military-academy/admission/), the equivalent of a masters degree, is a superb marksman, confident leadership style, strong physical fitness, etc. and would, under most normal circumstances make a prime candidate for agencies like the FBI or CIA.

> **AMBITIOUS RECRUIT:** (loud and formal) Jake Jensen, West Point, graduate with honors. We're here because you're looking for the best of the best of the best, sir!

Comment: And this is exactly why K does whisper in Zed's ear.  He's had to put up with the military recruits and knows they aren't really suitable.

Comment: @Dragonel - Sure, but J was probably too busy doing MiB stuff to sit in on the latest batch of recruitment, hence why his new partner is a putz